# issue with first element in nav bar having extra spacing

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav

My issue is that the first element in my nav bar which is "home" has more spacing than the rest of the elements. I can't seem for the life of me to figure out what it is. All I wanted was to have a centered evenly spaced out navigation bar but it's seeming harder than I thought.

**CSS**

```
.container {
width: 1060px;
background: #FFF;
padding: 50px;
margin: 0 auto;
}


#top_nav { 
position:fixed;
background:#343642;
font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
}

#top_nav ul { 
list-style:none; 
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
text-align:center;
overflow:hidden;
}

#top_nav ul li {
margin:0 56px 0 0;
padding: 0; 
font-size:1.7em; 
text-transform:uppercase; 
display: inline-block;
font-weight:bold;
}


#top_nav ul li a {
color:#fef6e9; 
text-decoration:none;
display: block;
}

#top_nav ul li a:hover {
color:#ed7163; 
text-decoration:none;
}


.content { padding: 10px 0;}

.content-outer { width:100%; overflow:visible; }

.content-outer .content-inner { width:100%; margin:0 auto; overflow:visible;        position:relative; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content-outer" id="top_nav">

                <ul>


<li><a href="#">Home</a><li>
<li><a href="#">Digital</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Film</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Timeline</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>                      
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are not properly closing the first `li` in your list.

`<li><a href="#">Home</a><li>`
should be

`<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>`

Consider running your code through a mark up validator like [W3C mark up validator](http://validator.w3.org/) when you are having formatting problems. Many times its something small like a mismatched tag or not properly closing a tag such as in this case.